What is the python object returned from a mysql select query?
When I run this following select query on the command line in Mysql:
SELECT date_sent FROM books;

I get this sort of result (eg) | 2024-10-06 |
but if I run the same select query from inside python:
   # Select query 
    cur.execute("SELECT date_sent FROM books") 
    output = cur.fetchall() 
    for i in output: 
        print(i)

I get this as a result (eg)  (datetime.date(2024, 10, 6),)
I don't understand what object this has returned, and how I can use it as a date.  I have tried splitting it like a text field, printing it as a list item, a tuple item or a dictionary item, but it seems untranslatable.

it's a datetime.date object. See the docs here → https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types

You can format a datetime.date instance as a string using method strftime.

You are being returned a datetime.date instance, which can be formatted as a string using method strftime.
    cur.execute("SELECT date_sent FROM books") 
    rows = cur.fetchall() 
    for row in rows:
        the_date = row[0]  # or row['date_sent'] if row is a dictionary
        print(the_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))  # for example, 10/06/2024


When you execute the query inside Python using cur.fetchall() it returns datetime.date object. If you want it to be formatted as string you can use strftime. In below example I have formatted as '%Y-%m-%d'
Output will be '2024-10-06'
cur.execute("SELECT date_sent FROM books") 
    output = cur.fetchall() 

for i in output:
    date_sent = i[0]  
    formatted_date = date_sent.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
    print(formatted_date) 

